# Why is there no prayer for the return of prophecy?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, nevua-prophecy

In our prayers we ask for the return of judges, the line of David as king and a return to Jerusalem among many other things. I am not aware of any prayer which asks for a return of prophecy, prophets or an individual request to achieve prophecy.

Does any such prayer exist as part of the formalized prayers included in any siddur nusach or denomination or has any such prayer existed previously (but is no longer in use)? If not, why not?

Comment: Is that something we want? (excluding the specific prophets messiah/elijah assuming they will be prophets, for which there are already prayers.)

Comment: The prayers were formalised when there was still prophecy, although the Anshei Knesset Hagedola did seem to be just about still around when prophecy ended

Comment: @RabbiKaii Common, there was also a Temple then and somehow we got prayers for that to come back.

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn't widespread prophecy assumed to be a feature of the messianic age? E.g. Joel 3:1

Comment: @JoelK If it's so ubiquitous it's arguably included in other general requests for that era, but anyway that doesn't answer my question. There are lots of things that will happen then that we don't specifically care to ask for. Do we specifically want more prophecy or will that just be a thing that happens whether we want it or not?

Comment: @DoubleAA very good point, although there seem to definitely be prophecies that the temple would be destroyed (e.g. Micah 3:12, Daniel 9:26), but nothing about the end of prophecy

Comment: Perhaps it is because prophecy is a *consequence* of the messianic era. All the abovementioned are prerequisites of the messianic era. For example, we do not pray that each man sit beneath his grape vine and date tree in equanimity (Mikhah 4:4). We trust in the prophets that such will typify the reality of that future era. In the interim we pray for those aspects which are prerequisites (and perhaps within our hands to bring about) that future.

Comment: Re-establishing our national courts, instituting the monarchy, building the Temple, establishing full sovereignty... these are all necessary for us to be able to dwell securely at peace and be able to achieve greater degrees of perfection (such as are reflected in those achieved by prophets).

Comment: @Deuteronomy I would argue, especially from Rambam's perspective, prophecy is an indication of the attainment of perfection, and should be a spiritual goal independents of the Messianic age

Comment: @DoubleAA see my previous comment, in general much of the orthodox Jewish world learns mesillat yesharim which is based on the beraita that indicates character refinement leads to prophecy which I would argue indicates (according to chazal) attainment of prophecy should be a personal goal. This is also true of the prophetic/ecstatic school of Kabbalah and would stand to reason logically that a person would want to achieve a direct connection with God such as is afforded to the prophet

Comment: @rikitikitembo attainment of character refinement and/or connection with God is the goal worth praying for, prophecy or not.

Comment: There is??? *Ve'yoatzeinu kevat'chilah*

Comment: @TheGRAPKE is there an indication that this refers to prophets?

Comment: @rikitikitembo political organization, security and welfare of citizenry, etc. are all components of achieving widespread perfection. The messianic era, in the Maimonidean framework, is a time wherein many may attain to perfection (and possibly prophecy). An environment of material abundance, free from geopolitical distraction, and governed by a leadership guided by a spirit of wisdom, leads to a more perfected population. It would then make sense to pray for the restoration of those elements that lead to such a future messianic state, as widespread perfection would be its natural consequence.

Comment: @rikitikitembo Heard from Rb Matisyahu Salomon.

Answer (score 6):

Prophecy only existed when there was an inclination for idol worship ([GRA on Seder Olam 30:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Vilna_Gaon_on_Seder_Olam_Rabbah.30.2.12)). The Sages prayed for the removal of that inclination and said "We do not want it, and we do not want its reward" ([Sanhedrin 64a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.64a.3-7)) i.e. prophecy. Praying for prophecy is the opposite of what they did.

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/1818773/Did_Prophecy_Cease 
does that mean we should not pray for Moshiach because the inclination to idolatry will return?

Comment: In the days of mashiach there will be no yetzer (Sukkah 52a https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.52a.2)

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam believed prophecy will return in the year 1216, independent of the Messiah's arrival.  This doesn't answer your question about the lack of a prayer, but it does show that the Gedolim looked forward to it:

> To come back to Balaam's prophecy, the verse "After the lapse of time, one will tell Jacob and Israel what God hath wrought," (Numbers 23:23), contains a veiled allusion to the date of the restoration of prophecy to Israel. The statement means that after the lapse of an interval equal to the time that passed from the Six Days of Creation to Balaam's day, seers will again tell Israel what God hath wrought. Now Balaam uttered his prediction in the thirty-eighth year after the Exodus which corresponds to the year 2485 after the Creation of the World, for the Exodus took place in the beginning of the year 2448. According to the interpretation of this chronology, prophecy would be restored to Israel in the year 4976 after the creation of the world [1216 CE]. [Iggeret Teman]

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/50201)