If prophecy ended, how come idol worship didn't?
The Vilna Gaon claims that the destruction of the yeitzer hara (evil inclination) for idol worship also removed prophecy.
I want to know, why? It seems there is a connection between the yeitzer hara for idol worship, and the ability to prophesy. Indeed, this is what I've been taught in the past: that the temptation to Avodah Zarah, and the ability to prophesy are two sides of the same coin. However, it seem unfair.
It seems more logical that the actual ability to prophesy should be connected to the ability to worship idols, not the temptation to worship idols. Yet we find that even though we have lost the ability to prophesy, we have not lost the ability to worship idols - an unfair bargain!
So why is it the case that the inclination to idol worship is not tied to the inclination to reach the heights of prophecy, but rather it is tied to the ability to prophesy, altogether?

Worshiping idols requires basic human motion that anyone can do. Very few people can do prophecy. Would you have everyone develop situational arthritis that prevents them from bowing when an idol is present?

@ClintEastwood no, but why can't the "very few" that you rightly mentioned no longer prophesy?

Because that was the (apparently) the price for removing the drive to worship idols from the world.

The only way to destroy the Dark Side was to weaken the Force.

I read your message many times and I still don't understand what you are asking.

Alternatively, maybe prophecy was only necessary to counterbalance the idol-worshiping urge.

@MauriceMizrahi see edit?

@shmosel that seems unfair, or at least the type of bargain that seems regretable. Why did the Sages elect for this? Some viable answers, possibly hinted above, are that the type of idol worship we have now is diluted so that it is incomparable, or maybe just comparable to the lower levels of Divine Inspiration that we have to replace prophecy?

@ClintEastwood see above comment re: that seems unfair

https://orot.com/product/lights-of-prophecy-orot-ha-nevuah/

@RabbiKaii -- I still don't get it.  Practicing idolatry is something you control with your willpower.  You have no control over prophecy, which is when God contacts you and tells you to transmit a message.  Where do you see a connection between the two?  See my question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110993/how-do-we-know-prophecy-ceased-in-israel

@MauriceMizrahi your line of thinking may be on the right lines (and if you feel you have an answer feel free to post it), but we do have information about how a prophet would train, and then prepare for a communion with Hashem, so it's not completely passive

My understanding is that the desire for idol worship and prophecy were both connected with a burning desire to see and feel God. When you had such a desire to be with God that you are willing to forgo all materialism (see I Sh'muel 19:24, Yesodei Hatorah 7:4), you would prophesize. (Avodah Zara was a shortcut where you would get these awesome close to god feelings without all the prep and hard work). The actions of serving God (mitzvot) are still available to do, so to are the actions of serving idols still available (and maybe some kavanot both ways).
If you look thru Navi, there are 3 types of kings: those who went in the path of David (II Kings 14:3, 16:2, 22:2), those who went in the path of Yeravam (II Kings 3:3, 13:2-4, 10:29...), and those who went in the path of Ahav (II Kings 8:27, 21:3). The first worshipped Hashem, the second worshipped Hashem but thru an illegal intermediary (calves), and the third worshipped foreign gods (baal).
The middle case of the calves seems to be not the classic Avodah Zara but more of a good Jewish boy version of Avodah Zara (I told this to someone and he said the GRA, R' Eliyahu Dessler and R' Avigdor Miller all agree but the Hazon Ish argues, no sources though).

+1 and wow thank you for those amazing insights, and yes I've heard about the connection with the burning desire. However, I still want to know why this desire, or at least prophecy itself is inaccessible completely. It seems that if that is the case, it's only fair that Avodah Zara is also completely inaccessible

Prophecy was a desire. So the corresponding desire was taken away. You can still worship God. You can still worship a"

So while the prophesy ended, the burning desire  did not, as we can find in the story about dosens of people rushing to dress as kohen gadol, go to kodesh hakodashim, and die there.

@ydj and the many people the gemara says were worthy but the generation wasn't (like Shmuel hakatan...). The mass desire ended even if certain individuals did have it. Leaders are based off of generation level

@Mordechai Shmuel Hakatan example is very good for your point. Can you expand on what you mean "prophecy was a desire"? Ideally add all this to the answer

@Mordechai we still have avoda zara, as RabbiKaii suggests. So burning desire should still exist, shouldn't it?

edited for both

The actions of mitzvot and avodah zara being equivalent is very interesting. Are you saying that the avodah zara of today is as disconnected from the past as mitzvot are disconnected from the level we did them during the times of prophecy? And that connection is the feeling/desire/kavana? What do you make of "we don't want them or their reward"?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/139049/24781

side note, they may have decided to abandom prophecy based on the verse that the temple was destroyed "because they left my Torah... and they did not listen to me" https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.9.12. The Yerushalmi https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Chagigah.1.7.4 states that Hashem wished they left Him and kept the Torah since the Torah would return them to Him automatically. I would propose leaving Hashem is leaving prophecy, and toiling in (oral) Torah which flourished during the second temple.
